# Deleting unwanted area of image using python

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to do iris segmentation using python. After doing some thresholding, in this process I want to get the black circle area (which is pupil) in the image that I attached, is there any process or method that I can get only the black circle area from the image? [Eyes Image that already thresholded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6wOK.png)

This is the original image
[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5OfT.jpg)

Comment: You would probably need to build a special NN, but nothing out of the box comes to mind. In any case it is better to ask specific questions about how a code works.

Comment: Can you share the original image?

Comment: I already add the original image